# In inittab, trying to set environment variable before executing script

Tags: linux, init

In inittab, I have an entry that looks like this:

```
scpt:234:once:RSYNC_OPTIONS=-q /path/to/script/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1
```

However, it fails because it's actually attempting to execute `RSYNC_OPTIONS=-q`. I've also tried:

```
scpt:234:once:export RSYNC_OPTIONS=-q;/path/to/script/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1
```

but that fails too. Is there a way to do this or do I have to modify the script?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of the Linux sysvinit implementation, it does run a shell when it sees shell special characters, but it adds `exec` before the string, which makes it possible to put redirections and use special characters in arguments but not to set an environment variable in this way.

> ```c
>   } else if (strpbrk(proc, "~`!$^&*()=|\\{}[];\"'<>?")) {
>   /* See if we need to fire off a shell for this command */
>         /* Give command line to shell */
>         args[1] = SHELL;
>         args[2] = "-c";
>         strcpy(buf, "exec ");
>         strncat(buf, proc, sizeof(buf) - strlen(buf) - 1);
>         args[3] = buf;
>         args[4] = NULL;
> ```

A straightforward solution would be to run `env`.

```
scpt:234:once:env RSYNC_OPTIONS=-q /path/to/script/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1
```

Some possible workarounds to illustrate how to run an arbitrary command:

```
scpt:234:once:>&1; RSYNC_OPTIONS=-q exec /path/to/script/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1
scpt:234:once:2>&1; RSYNC_OPTIONS=-q exec /path/to/script/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: +1 for creative workarounds; [debian source](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/sysvinit.git/tree/src/init.c#n994) for the rest of the init story.